# How to create Google Calendar event with specific recurrence using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

Problem creating Google Calendar event with URL.

```js
console.log(`RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=${recurrencia}`) //RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE
    const enlaceBase = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE';
    const parametros = [
        'text=' + encodeURIComponent(titulo),
        'recur=' + encodeURIComponent(`RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=${recurrencia}`), // Repetición semanal los martes y jueves
        'location=' + encodeURIComponent(ubicacion),
        'details=' + encodeURIComponent(descripcion + ` Para más información, <a href="${enlace}">visita este enlace</a>`)
    ];
    return enlaceBase + '&' + parametros.join('&');
```

URL seems like [this](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Kizomba%20Iniciaci%C3%B3n%20-%20Mier.%2017h&recur=RRULE%3AFREQ%3DWEEKLY%3BBYDAY%3DWE&location=Calle%20Canal%2015%2C%2031015%2C%20Pamplona&details=%20%20Para%20m%C3%A1s%20informaci%C3%B3n%2C%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Ffitfox.app%2Factividad%2F4596%22%3Evisita%20este%20enlace%3C%2Fa%3E). As you can see it selects in the options the selected one is each week (right) the monday (I think it's because today is monday). Do I have to specify the next wednesday to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Tried putting BYDAY=WE but I get each monday (Suposing it's actual date).
Any idea?

**Solution**: I created a new Date and setted the date to next day of recurring event. That worked.